# Split String But Delimiters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.4

I'm trying to convert a string to list, and I've tried `split` and `findall` but no luck. Also, I'd like to avoid `for` loops....

Sample:

```
import re

string2list = "[{u'name': u'a', u'number': u'123', u'addr': u'123 
sunshine'}, {u'name': u'b', u'number': u'456', u'addr': u'123 sunset'}]"

print re.findall('[^},]+},', string2list)
print re.split('[},]', string2list)
print re.split('[},] + }', string2list)`
```

Desired output is a list of the original string:

```
[{u'name': u'a', u'number': u'123', u'addr': u'123 
sunshine'}, {u'name': u'b', u'number': u'456', u'addr': u'123 sunset'}]
```

EDIT: 
Python version <=2.7.

EDIT 2:
This almost works, just missing `}`:

`print string2list.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split('}')`

EDIT 3: 
Using `eval`.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: WHICH version on Python?

Comment: @dawg should work from 2.4 & up.

Comment: @dawg I think this might need reopening.

Comment: Probably your only choice is `eval` then but that is not at all a good choice. You could also look at an older version of [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com)

Comment: @coldspeed: Reason? Every good answer to this (eval, PyParsing, JSON, regex) and for older versions is covered by the linked duplicate.

Comment: @dawg thank you for the input, I'll review `pyParsing`. In the meantime, can you please open the question to solicit other opinions? Maybe there is a regex ninja here. The answers that listed in the other question do not cover this scenario (2.4).

Comment: @dawg `pyParsing` isn't an option. Surely there is a way to do it natively in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The regex module is the wrong tool for this job.

You need `literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

string2list = "[{u'name': u'a', u'number': u'123', u'addr': u'123 
sunshine'}, {u'name': u'b', u'number': u'456', u'addr': u'123 sunset'}]"

print literal_eval(string2list)
# [{u'addr': u'123sunshine', u'name': u'a', u'number': u'123'},
#  {u'addr': u'123 sunset', u'name': u'b', u'number': u'456'}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm dealing with Python older than 2.7.

Comment: @Simply_me This is something you better mention in your question.

Comment: @Simply_me `literal_eval` was introduced in Python 2.6. If you are using an even earlier version than that, then.. all I have to say is good luck :)

Comment: I've edited the question. Ideally it should be done w/regex.

Comment: @Simply_me You are assuming that this *can* be done with regex.

Comment: yes you re right.